# Soundness and completeness of proposition logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I managed to prove that

1. a set $\Gamma $ is inconsistent if and only if  $\Gamma \vdash a$ where $a$ is an arbitrary wff
2. a set $\Gamma $ is inconsistent if and only if  $\Gamma \vDash b$ where $b$ is an arbitrary wff

Is it appropriate make a conclusion that the selected axiomatization of propositional logic is strongly sound and strongly complete (e.g., $\Gamma \vdash c$ if and only if $\Gamma \vDash c$) based solely on the two statements above?

Comment: You can see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988667/is-consistency-the-same-as-sound-or-complete-in-mathematical-logic) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189359/relationship-between-consistency-strong-completeness-and-soundness).

Comment: the language "where $a$ is an arbitrary wff" seems open to misinterpretation; better to say simply "for every wff $a$". This makes it clear why (1) and (2) do not imply soundness and competeness; given just $\Gamma\vdash a$ for one particular $a$ (1) does not say anything.